# calling namespace-uri in C#, namespace-uri has an invalid token

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am executing the following.
Given an XDocument doc;

```
doc.XPathEvaluate("//namespace-uri()");
```

I get the error '//namespace-uri()' has an invalid token.

It seems to work in a node test, for example "//*[namespace-uri()='xyz']".
The function should work though, XMLSPY is happy with the above version, and I believe it uses the same engine.

Any help would be appreciated.
I want to enumerate all the namespaces in the document using xpath.

Thanks
Regards
Craig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XPath is wrong. The `namespace-uri()` function returns a string, so it can't be used where a nodeset is expected. Instead, you should use the `namespace` axis:

```
doc.XPathEvaluate("//namespace::*");
```

This will return a nodeset containing every namespace declaration in the document.